# check if activity is the first since launch

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want my main activity to show a popup the on launch, this activity is the first activity that is created, but multiple instances of this activity could be created and I only want the first since launch to display this popup, so I would like to know if there how I can check this.

Comment: get "alreadyShown" from SharedPreferences if == false then show form and put "alreadyShow" = true into SharedPreferences

Comment: that will work if the app is not already on the market

Comment: @blackbelt . . What? He is asking how to know when the activity has already been opened once. Like if a new user is viewing the main activity for the first time.

Comment: @inner_class7 still if the app is on the market the activity could be already launched

Comment: I meant the first time the first time the activity is called since launch of the app not the first time the activity is called on this device ever. as far as I know sharedpreferences persist even after completely terminating the app.

Comment: View the code below, I believe this is how it should be. No matter how many times you launch this activity after the first time, the value will always be 1. Then at the end of your application, you can rewrite the value to SharedPreferences as 0 before you initial activity is finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simplest way of doing it is use a **static variable**

**How do you use it:**

Define a static boolean flag and assign it false value, once the activity is created for the first time, make the flag true, and now you do your task with simple `if/else` condition

```
public static boolean flag=false;
```

then in `onCreate`

```
if(flag==true)
{
    //Activity is not calling for first time now
}

if(flag==false)
{
    //first time calling activity
      flag=true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Store flag in `SharedPreferences` which indicate is application is launched first time or not. Use Activity Oncreate method as:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     // Create and check SharedPreferences if fist time launch 
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("showpopup", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    if(settings.contains("firsttime")){
           // means activity not launched first time
     }else{
        // means activity launched first time
       //store value in SharedPreferences as true
       editor.putBoolean("firsttime", true); 
       editor.commit();
           //show popup 
     }
}
```

Comment: I meant the first time the first time the activity is called since launch of the app not the first time the activity is called on this device ever. as far as I know sharedpreferences persist even after completely terminating the app.

Answer (score 1):

I would use selvins approach. Unless you have a backend to your application setup and user registration, there will be no way for you to get this type of information for a specific application instance unless you use `SharedPreferences`

```
int activityLaunchCount = 0;

SharedPreferences preferences = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", SharedPreferences.MODE_PRIVATE);
 activityLaunchCount = preferences.getInt("ActivityLaunchCount", 0);

if(activityLaunchCount < 1)
{
   // ** This is where you would launch you popup **
   // ......

   // Then you will want to do this: 
   // Get the SharedPreferences.Editor Object used to make changes to shared preferences
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

   // Then I would Increment this counter by 1, so if will never popup again.
   activityLaunchCount += 1;

   // Store the New Value
   editor.putInt("ActivityLaunchCount", activityLaunchCount);

   // You Must call this to make the changes
   editor.commit(); 

}else{

// If you application is run one time, this will continue to execute each subsequent time.
// TODO: Normal Behavior without showing a popup of some sort before proceeding.

}
```

Then when you want to Close the application

`Override` the `Activity` finish() method

```
@Override public void finish()
{
  super.finish();

  // Get the SharedPreferences.Editor Object used to make changes to shared preferences
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();


   // Store the New Value
   editor.putInt("ActivityLaunchCount", 0);

   // You Must call this to make the changes
   editor.commit(); 

}
```